# FishEye SmartCommits with an external repository

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, plasticscm, atlassian-fisheye

Are [Smart Commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+smart+commits) supported by external repositories (LightSCM)?

I'm developing an **external repository provider** for [PlasticSCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/home.html) and I would like to do the following using the PlasticSCM checkin (commit) message:

- close/resolve JIRA issues
- create Crucible reviews

I'm not sure if the API supports it.